# Extending background image beyond viewport on scrolling

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am using an image of library bookshelves as a background for my webpage. It is repeatable and works well on a single viewport. On top of that I have a DIV with another background, which is bigger than viewport. Here what I have in my styles.css:

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/library4.jpg");
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.article {
    background-image: url("images/old-paper.jpg");
    width: 95%;
}
```

However, when I scroll down, background does not show below. See what I am getting

[image: Here how it looks]

I did try all imaginable CSS options, like height: auto, etc. but nothing works. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: perhaps [background-repeat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat) might be of interest

Comment: I tried it and it didn't help

Comment: its impossible to say whats going wrong if there is no replicable example code. Can you provide us with a code snippet demonstrating your issue?

Comment: did you try ```background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat;``` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The culprit was just to change the scope of the background image. I.e. instead of

```
body {
    background-image: url("images/library4.jpg");
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I placed

```
html {
    background-image: url("images/library4.jpg");
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```